# Apply a kernel selection since a value of the same function?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have created a list of kernels that can be applied from the average value of an image, this is the [code]:https://code.earthengine.google.com/107f6dff6906eb1dab79013ad1d06b43

```
// Create a list of weights for a 3x3 kernel.
//kernel direccion norte;
var weights_N = [[0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 1, 0],
                 [2, 2, 2]];
//kernel direccion norte-este;
var weights_NE= [[0, 0, 0],
                 [2, 1, 0],
                 [2, 2, 0]];
//kernel direccion este;
var weights_E = [[2, 0, 0],
                 [2, 1, 0],
                 [2, 0, 0]];
//kernel direccion sur-este;
var weights_SE = [[2, 2, 0],
                 [2, 1, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0]];
//kernel direccion sur;
var weights_S = [[2, 2, 2],
                 [0, 1, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0]];
//kernel direccion sur-oeste;
var weights_SO = [[0, 2, 2],
                 [0, 1, 2],
                 [0, 0, 0]];
//kernel direccion oeste;
var weights_O = [[0, 0, 2],
                 [0, 1, 2],
                 [0, 0, 2]];
//kernel direccion nor-oeste;
var weights_NO = [[0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 1, 2],
                 [0, 2, 2]]; 

// Create the kernel from the weights.
var kernel1 = ee.Kernel.fixed({weights: weights_N});
print(kernel1);
```

Depending on the mean value of this image, a kernel will be applied:

```
var ERA5 = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5/MONTHLY").first();
// Wind speed and direction
//---
// Based on code from Gennadii Donchyts
// https://code.earthengine.google.com/320ee5bc81f2de3ae49f348f8ec9a6d7
  var uv0 = ERA5.select(['u_component_of_wind_10m', 'v_component_of_wind_10m']);
  
    var uv10 = uv0.clip(ee.Feature(geometry));

var ERA5winddir = uv10.expression(
    'mod(180 + (180/3.14) * atan2(v,u),360)', {
      'u': uv10.select('u_component_of_wind_10m'),
      'v': uv10.select('v_component_of_wind_10m')
  }).rename('winddir');

var wind_mean = ERA5winddir.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());

print(wind_mean);

Map.addLayer(ERA5winddir.select('winddir'), vis, "Wind dir", false);

// Reduce the region. The region parameter is the Feature geometry.
var meanDictionary = ERA5winddir.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
  geometry: ERA5winddir.geometry(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});

// The result is a Dictionary.  Print it.
print(meanDictionary);
```

How could I create a conditional function to select the kernel?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to avoid flow conditionals (and loops) in Earth Engine whenever possible.  In this case, the easiest solution is probably to create a list of kernels and convert the mean value into an index into the list.

Assuming "east" means 0° and "north" means 90° (double check; that changes depending on the projection you're computing in and which way +y is pointing) and you want to use the north kernel for everything from 67.5° to 112.5° (90° ± 22.5°), then it'd be something like this:

```
var kerneList = [E, NE, N, NW, W, SW, S, SE, E]
var index = mean.divide(45).round()
var kernel = kerneList.get(index)
```